# What is an 'obstacle vista diagram'?

Tags: meteorology, wind, remote-sensing

Currently I do some research about SODAR and at [this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1352231097003853/1-s2.0-S1352231097003853-main.pdf?_tid=982ada2c-a959-4c4d-af9c-1e5de179c7da&acdnat=1522340401_61816cf131c03b50bbfc47eb9ab31617), the author wrote (p. 1502f):

> A site should be relatively clear of obstacles that could act as
>   potential fixed-echo reflectors. If that is not possible, then it is
>   therefore important to construct an **obstacle vista diagram** prior to
>   sodar installation  which  identifies  the  direction  and  height 
>   of potential reflectors in relation to the sodar (Baxter, 1994, 1996).
>   This diagram can be used after some data have been collected to assess
>   whether or not reflections are of concern at some sodar height ranges.

Unfortunately, I can't find any access to the referenced literature and google wasn't helpful either. So, what is an obstacle vista diagram and how to construct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just taking a guess from the context, I think it could be a "view shed", the term used in GIS (Geographic Information Systems) to refer to a visibility analysis. In other words, it is a calculation that determines which areas of a given terrain would be visible from a specific point.

It is used to know, for example, what would be the coverage of a radio transmitter on a given location, or from which areas would a lighthouse not be visible, etc. To calculate such diagram you need a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) of the area.

To give you an example I just loaded a DEM and run a calculation (using Global Mapper) of the areas visible from a 20 meters tall tower in the top of a specific hill, and within a 40 km radius. And this is how the results looks like:
[image]

Where the red shading show the areas that are visible from the tower. The rest of the terrain would be hidden behind topographic obstacles.